# Use of execle with wget command

Tags: c, exec, wget

I have edited my previous question.

As I had got the problem and the changed the code, now I have a different problem. If I use execle command, it only downloads one image using the wget command, otherwise it prints all the image names on the screen if the wget command does not execute. I do not understand when there is a while loop, then why does it only print one image.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int iFlag;
char cline[100];
FILE*fil = fopen("index.html","rt");
if(fil==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening file");
}
char*tmpLine;
char*tok;
const char check[10] = "<img";
const char check2[10] = "src=";
char images[50];
strcpy(images,argv[1]);
while(fgets(cline,100,fil)!=NULL)
{
    if(strstr(cline,check)!=NULL)
    {
        tmpLine=strstr(cline,check);
        if(strstr(cline,check2)!=NULL)
        {
            tmpLine=strstr(cline,check2);
            tok = strtok(tmpLine,"\"");
            while(tok!=NULL)
            {
                tok = strtok(NULL,"\"");
                if(tok[0]!='/')
                {
                    strcat(images,"/");
                    strcat(images,tok);
                    printf("\nimage: %s\n",images);
                    iFlag = execle("/usr/bin/wget","wget","-o","logfile",images,NULL);
                    if(iFlag<0)
                      perror("EXECLE ERROR");
                    break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            memset(&images[0], 50, sizeof(images));
            strcpy(images,argv[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

A big problem is that the `exec` family of function *replaces* your process with that of the new program. That means that if the call to `execle` succeeds your program no longer exists.

You need to `fork` a new process if you want your own program to continue.

Comment: Is this a good substitute for that?
    char*tmp = "wget -o logfile ";

    char*temp = (char*)malloc(tmp+(sizeof(images)));

    strcpy(temp,tmp);

    strcat(temp,images);

    system(temp);